# Cannot install Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

Hello i made a usb stick for install elementary os but i got an error in installation.
Error is :

mount: mounting dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed such as no file or directory

Comment: Did you [verify](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium) your download?

Comment: I too experience the same error :-( I used rufus 3.11 to write the downloaded elementary image I tried both ISO and dd same result :-(
Pressing e or space gives no option to verify the boot disk :-( Rufus's verify gives a SHA256 that looks exactly the same as the one from elementary's site.
I've made a kde neon image, boots fine, from same stick

Comment: Same issue -- installed with UNetbootin on a USB drive, the ISO download was verified. How to proceed?